# Progressively add types for a 3rd party javascript module

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I've just been tasked with converting a fairly large project from Javascript to Typescript. One of the difficulties is that one of the 3rd-party modules we are using is also in Javascript, but ideally we'd like to add the types for that as well. This 3rd-party module is used extensively throughout the codebase, so we'd like to add the types progressively.

So, let's say we have two components like this:

```
// -----| FirstComponentConsumer.tsx |-------------------------
import { FirstComponent } from 'third-party';

export const FirstComponentConsumer = () => {
  return (
    <FirstComponent name="pants" />
  );
};

// -----| SecondComponentConsumer.tsx |------------------------
import { SecondComponent } from 'third-party';

export const SecondComponentConsumer = () => {
  return (
    <SecondComponent type="text" />
  );
};
```

Now, I'd like to add the types for `FirstComponent` but not `SecondComponent` YET - I'll add these later (in reality there are hundreds of exports that will need to be typed). So I can create my types file, something like:

```
// types.d.ts 
import type { ReactNode } from 'react';

declare module 'third-party' {
  export type FirstComponentProps = {
    name?: string;
  }

  export const FirstComponent = (props: FirstComponentProps) => ReactNode;
}
```

This works as expected - `FirstComponent` is now typed! But, it breaks `SecondComponentConsumer` because I haven't said that the `third-party` module exports a `SecondComponent`:

```
Module '"third-party"' has no exported member 'SecondComponent'.  TS2305
```

Of course this makes perfect sense, but can I turn off this checking for "undeclared types"? Or is that trying to have my cake and eat it too?

Comment: When you say it breaks SecondComponentConsumer, what breaks exactly?

Comment: @DocCaliban - anything that's imported without being declared gets a TS2305 error ('no exported member'). I'll update the question to reflect this!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this might do the trick, basically you are just exporting everything as any, but specifically typing a single component.  I haven't tested this, but I think it should work.

```
declare module "third-party" {
    const FirstComponent: (name?: string) => ReactNode;

    type Exports = {
        FirstComponent: typeof FirstComponent;
    } & {
        [key: PropertyKey]: any;
    }

    const exports: Exports;

    export default exports;

    export { FirstComponent };
}
```

Comment: Nope, unfortunately it gives the same error. I tried playing around with something along these lines, I can make it error with TS2614 instead of TS2305, but still an error.